# Why does the list seem to have the wrong number of items

Tags: python, list, opencv

I have the following Python script where I'm trying to save pairs of images in a list:

```
import os
import os.path
import cv2
from collections import namedtuple

path = '/Users/abc/Desktop/images'
pairs = []

# initialization
img1 = None
img2 = None
Img = namedtuple('Img', ['data', 'name'])

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith('1'):
            im1 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '1.jpg')
            im1_file = '1.jpg'
            img1 = Img(im1,im1_file)
            print 'passed from here'
        elif file.startswith('2'):
            im2 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '2.jpg')
            im2_file = '2.jpg'
            img2 = Img(im2,im2_file)
            print 'passed from here'

        pair = (img1,img2)
        pairs.append(pair)


[p for p in pairs if p is not (None,None)]

print len(p)

for img in p:
    print img.name
```

I have 2 subdirectories, each of which has two `images 1.jpg` and `2.jpg`. The output of the above script is:

```
passed from here
passed from here
passed from here
passed from here
2
1.jpg
2.jpg
```

It seems that the loop goes through all the 4 images in the two subdirectories, but why do I only get `1.jpg` and `2.jpg` instead of:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
1.jpg
2.jpg
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is `len(pairs)` before you filter it?

Comment: It gives me "5", which I believe is correct, including the initialization (None,None). So, it is 4 items + the None pairs. What happened in the filtering step in this case? Is there an easier way to remove the initialization (None,None)?

Comment: you need to assign the filtering to a variable: `result = [p for p in pairs if p not (None, None)]`

Answer (score 0):

Because p is the last pair of pairs. So you want:

```
for p in pairs:
    for img in p:
        print img.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I got this error: "File "create_pair.py", line 38, in <module>
    print img.name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'"

Answer (score 0):

What I think could be the problem is you are using wrong variable `p`.

As far as I can see, you didn't assign your filtered result. `[p for p in pairs if p is not (None,None)]`, and here `p` is just an intermediate variable inside this list comprehension. `p` should equal to the last item inside `pairs`.

You should save it first:

```
results = [p for p in pairs if p is not (None,None)]

print len(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick fixed, for your reference.

```
path = '/Users/abc/Desktop/images'
pairs = []

# initialization
img1 = None
img2 = None
Img = namedtuple('Img', ['data', 'name'])

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.startswith('1'):
            im1 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '1.jpg')
            im1_file = '1.jpg'
            img1 = Img(im1,im1_file)
            print 'passed from here'
        elif file.startswith('2'):
            im2 = cv2.imread(root + '/' + '2.jpg')
            im2_file = '2.jpg'
            img2 = Img(im2,im2_file)
            print 'passed from here'

    pair = (img1,img2) # unindent these two lines
    pairs.append(pair) # unindent these two lines

# you need save the result to a variable.
valid_pair = [p for p in pairs if p is not (None,None)]
# p is the last pair when you iterate the pairs list.
print len(p) # The pair is a tuple, has two elements, so length is 2.

for img in p: # p is a tuple, so you can iterate it successfully.
    print img.name  #print img1.name,print img2.name
# you need iterate the valid_pair!
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. The result is the same as I had in my question.